# DBExpress TSQLConnection timeout

Tags: mysql, delphi, dbexpress

(Using Delphi 2010 Pro 32bit Windows via LAN/WAN to server Ubuntu with MySQL 5.5)
When accessing Remote MySQL server, my app sometimes freezes for 20 secs before it reports "MySQL gone away". 
In practice I think this is caused by a *brief* loss of network connection, (which I dont control), so I need to try to reconnect much faster than this - maybe after 2-3 secs.

I have tried changing TMySQLConnection Connect timeout, but it makes no difference -  either is not implemented, or does nothing?? (Remy?? can you confirm?)

Is there a way to get control of my app back *faster* when I get this error?
(I am *sure* that I would be able to reconnect if able to retry 2-3 secs later!)

Thanks

Chris H

Comment: Chris, I do not think that dbExpress or DataSnap actually support the connectTimeout property, from memory the DBX connections do not support it.

Comment: Yes, suspect you are right - hoping that Remy will comment as I belive the DBExpress stuff is basically "Indy"